# Redshift new cluster used to be accessible but not anymore

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Last week, I was able to successfully connect to Redshift clusters. This week I am unable to connect even though I gave same configs for the following:

- Virtual Private Cloud VPC
- Security Groups
- Cluster subnet group
- Publicly accessible Cluster permissions

But this week I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "create_staging_tables.py", line 93, in <module>
    conn = psycopg2.connect(
  File "/Users/bsubramanian/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Operation timed out
    Is the server running on host "clustername.region.redshift.amazonaws.com" (54.243.82.201) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5439?
```

when running from a Python script which is used to connect to redshift cluster and create some tables.

How do I debug what is wrong?

Comment: Is the question about creating a Redshift cluster or connecting to it?  Your code is about  connecting but you state "This week I am unable to create"

Comment: changed it to `connect`

Answer (score 1):

Typically these issues are network related.  Checking connectivity from your client system to the database is a good start.

First off check the connection information - go to the Redshift console and confirm the IP address given in the error message is the IP address of the leader node.  If these don't match your code has some wrong configuration.  (Note that Redshift can also have a public IP if you configured the cluster as such.  Most users don't do this for security reasons.  If you do you likely should be using that IP address.)

Next a simple test of network connectivity is a good step.  The Linux command telnet can do this - telnet  5439.  Now telnet cannot talk to Redshift but if you get any response other than a time out telnet is able to make the initial connection to Redshift.  If this doesn't work then a lot more information about your network configuration will be needed to debug.

Now all of this assumes you don't have a connection pool server in between your client and the DB.  It looks to be the case but ...

If you can connect via IP address but not with the cluster DNS name then a DNS issue is likely.  We'll need more info on your DNS setup (and some on the network).  This doesn't look to be the issue but ...

If telnet can connect but your client cannot (with the same info) then it could be a security group configuration issue.

There are lots of possibilities.  Start by checking the connection info and update the issue as you learn more.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by creating new instances of the following

- Virtual Private Cloud(VPC)
- VPC Security Group
- Cluster Subnet group